# Run contentscript on extension load instead of page load

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have an extension that gets auto-installed in the domain. But, chrome in the domain is configured to start with a specific page.

The extension is configured to load a content script on this specific page through the manifest. When you navigate the page, this works perfectly. But, on the first login, the page is already open, and the extension is loaded/installed AFTER it. It does not trigger injecting the content script.

How can I make sure it injects the contentscript as soon as the extension is loaded?

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches":["<all_urls>"],
    "js":[
      "content_script.js"
    ],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
```

The issue now is, new users are confused when opening a Chromebook on Guest mode because the content-script is not working the first time.

They need to close and reopen the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle this case by yourself, injecting scripts after install manually.

On your background page just check is it first run or not and then, on the first run you need to call [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  file: 'contentScript.js'
});
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#functionality).

Comment: But how to test? When trying on loading it unpacked, I get an error that I cannot inject on chrome:// urls. Which is the extension page. ... I might have to check the current active tab!